# CodeBlocks compile error when running Vroom build

Tags: c++

First time I've tried compiling (on Windows) the Vroom Routing source using makefile, but some pkg-config error popped up.

I am now trying to compile the vroom source using CodeBlocks + MinGW and I get the following error:

`#include "structures/vroom/solution/solution.h" - there is no such file or directory.`

[Image of my folder structure attached here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aWgrZ.png)

The folder structure is correct but I don't understand what I'm doing wrong.
Is there any other way to configure Vroom Routing?

Thanks in advance!

Comment:  Please post code, errors, sample data or textual output here as plain-text, not as images that can be hard to read, can’t be copy-pasted to help test code or use in answers, and are barrier to those who depend on screen readers or translation tools. You can edit your question to add the code in the body of your question. For easy formatting use the `{}` button to mark blocks of code, or indent with four spaces for the same effect. The contents of a **screenshot can’t be searched, run as code, or copied and edited to create a solution.**

Comment: Best guess - you need to add structures/vroom/solution/ to the compiler search path.  Project | build options |  Search directories | Compiler